# Shower drain 2 inch reduce to 1.5 inch

Tags: bathroom, shower

I am removing my bath tub and installing walk in shower drain shower is 2 inch but tun drain 1.5 inch I need to reducer any one can help me what kind adapter or reducer I need to use ?
Thank you

Comment: You might want to consider changing the 1.5" to 2" especially if there are several bends in it. I have a 2" in both of my showers and the pan will get about 1" of water after a few minutes of showering. I have a good water supply at about 60 PSIG maybe a bit more.

Comment: Unscrew the sower drain and get the right size one

Comment: Any good plumbing shop will supply your needs, when you arrive with the one part that's transportable, and measurements of the fixed pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the best solution is to run the entire run from sewer main line to shower with 2" pipe and fittings. There is a reason this is the law for plumbing fixtures (at least here in the USA).

You have not stated whether you have access to the underfloor plumbing (raised floor/ crawlspace ? or concrete slab ?).

To answer your question, what you need to go from 1 1/2" to 2" pipe is called a reducer coupling, or a bell reducer. Attached pic is in ABS pipe.

[image]